# What are the generators of $\mathbb{Z}_9^*$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am to understand that $\mathbb{Z}_9^*$ is cyclic because $9=3^2$, where $3^2$ is of the form $p^{\alpha}$, with $p$ an odd prime... but I can't find any generators for the set...

$|\mathbb{Z}_9^*|=6$, and $\mathbb{Z}_9^*=\{\overline{1},\overline{2},\overline{4},\overline{5},\overline{7},\overline{8}\}$

Using a table:

\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
\cdot & 1 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 8 \\\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 2 & 4 \\
4 & 4 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 4 & 7 \\
5 & 5 & 7 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 5 \\
7 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 4 \\
8 & 8 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 8 & 1 \\
\end{array}

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the definition of a generator, but since I'm assuming that $\mathbb{Z}_9^*$ is cyclic, it should have $\varphi(\varphi(9))=2$ generators... but I can't find a single one.

Comment: Why is your table listing $1\cdot2=1$ et cetera? Several other errors in there, too.

Comment: $2*1 = 2, 2*2 = 4, 2*4 = 8, 2*5 = 1, 2*7 = 5, 2*8 = 7$, so $\overline{2}$ is a generator.

Comment: There are so many errors, it's no wonder you can't find generators. Find the usual products, then reduce each mod $9$.

Comment: Where are my errors? I've gone over this twice and I got the same thing each time.

Comment: $2*4=8$ which mod $9$ is $8$ not $7$.

Comment: @coffeemath but I thought I had to take $2^4=16\equiv 7\mod{9}$

Comment: On any group table each element occurs exactly once on each row and column. At some points it looks like you are calculating the residue of $a^b$ as opposed to $a\cdot b$.

Comment: @coffeemath notice the headers in my table. Are the headers wrong? I listed all the elements $n$ such that $(n,9)=1$

Comment: The group operation is multiplication - not power.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But that seems contrary to what I was taught... but again I may have misunderstood

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Wouldn't that mean that every element in $\mathbb{Z}_9^*$ is a generator, save for $\overline{1}$?

Comment: The following may be what is confusing you. To test whether $a$ is a generator you have to calculate the powers $a^0$, $a^1$, $a^2$, $a^3$ et cetera and check whether you get all the elements. The exponent can be any natural number.

Comment: So for example $4^1=4$, $4^2=7$, $4^3=1$ and you get these three elements repeated. Conclusion $4$ is not a generator. OTOH $2^1=2$, $2^2=4$, $2^3=8$, $2^4=7$, $2^5=5$, $2^6=1$. Bingo! We got all the elements as powers of two, so it is a generator.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen OK, then from the table alone, assuming I correct it to use multiplication instead of powers, can I find a generator from it? Or do I have to test each one individually with the method above?

Comment: In any group, whenever you write a power $a^n$, the exponent $n$ is treated as an integer. It just counts the number of factors in $a\cdot a\cdot a\cdots a$. The exponent $n$ has nothing to do with elements of the group.

Comment: Here testing all the elements is not too arduous. But you know that the group is cyclic of order six. There is a general result that if an element $a$ generates a cyclic group of order $n$, then $a^i$ also generates the same group if and only if $\gcd(i,n)=1$. So now that you have $2$ as a generator you can look for powers $2^i$ where $\gcd(i,6)=1$. Those are also generators.

Answer (score 1):

When you are looking for generators, a trick to reduce the work is to note that, once you know that $a$ is **not** a generator, then neither is any power $a^i$. So in your case you'd start by testing $2$ rather than $2^2=4$ or $2^3=8$.

A good way to check $a$ is a generator module ${\mathbb Z}_{p^k}^\times$ is to check whether $a^{\phi(p^k) / q} \not\equiv 1(\bmod. p^k)$ for each prime $q$ dividing $\phi(p^k)$. In thi scase, you can check $2$ is a generator.

More generally, $2$ is a generator of ${\mathbb Z}_{3^k}^{\times}$ for each $k=1,2,3\ldots$. The proof goes as follows:

*Lemma:* $2^{2\times 3^{k-1}} = 3^k \times q + 1$ for some $q\in {\mathbb Z}$ with $3 \not | q$.

Proof: For $k=1$ this is trivial, indeed $2^2 = 3\times 1 + 1$ and clearly $3\not | 1$.

Assume the result to hold for some $k$, now for $k+1$ we note that:

\begin{align} 2^{2^\times 3^k} = \left(2^{2\times 3^{k-1}} \right)^3 = (3^k \times q + 1)^3 &= 3^{3k} q^3 + 3 \times 3^{2k} q^2 + 3 \times 3^k q + 1 \end{align}

which is of the form $3^{k+1} q^\prime + 1$ where $q^\prime = 3^{2k-1} q^3 + 3^{k}q^2 + q$, now since $3 \not | q$ and $k\geq 1$, we get that $3\not | q^\prime$, finishing the induction. $\square$

Now, with this lemma, note that if the order of $2$ modulo $3^k$ were not $\phi(3^k) = 2 \times 3^{k-1}$, then it'd either divide $2\times 3^{k-2}$ or $3^{k-1}$ (by taking out one prime factor from each, this is the "least we can take out"). The latter is impossible since $2^{3^{k-1}} \equiv -1 (\bmod. 3)$ and so $2^{3^{k-1}} \equiv 1 (\bmod. 3^k)$ is impossible since it'd imply  $2^{3^{k-1}} \equiv 1 (\bmod. 3)$.

So, suppose the order of $2$ were $2\times 3^{k-2}$, we showed a moment ago that $2^{2\times 3^{k-2}} = 3^{k-1} \times q + 1$ where $3\not | q$, so $2^{2\times 3^{k-2}} \equiv 1(\bmod. 3^{k})$ is impossible since it would imply $3^{k-1} \times q \equiv 0(\bmod. 3^k)$ yet $3\not | q$.