# Whate are the generators of $\mathbb{Z}_9^*$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Code in Python:

```
python3
[[(y**x) % 9 for x in range(9)] for y in range(9)]
```

Output:

> [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 4,
>   8, 7, 5, 1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 4, 7, 1, 4, 7, 1,
>   4, 7], [1, 5, 7, 8, 4, 2, 1, 5, 7], [1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1,
>   7, 4, 1, 7, 4, 1, 7, 4], [1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1, 8, 1]]

**How to**

We seek numbers from [1;9[ high 0-8 gives us all elements of [1;9[. The problem is that there is no such number. So there are no generators. Somehow I feel that I did a big mistake. What did I do wrong?

Comment: The elements in the multiplicative group have to be relatively prime to $9$.  Thus they are $\{1,2,4,5,7,8\}$. Powers of $2$ generate all them, for example.

Comment: Another question exists with the exact title *"What are the generators of $\mathbb{Z}_9^*$?"* - [MSE 542921](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542921). Aren't there other possibilities than to misspell this one?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was assuming that $\mathbb Z_9^\times = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. The unit group of $\mathbb Z_9 := \mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z$ is smaller than that.